thingsboard in edge has endless loop
When a node that generates alarms in the rule chain on the edge is triggered, the customer attribute node is triggered without any reason.
While the alarm is generated and not cleared yet, the customer attribute node keeps being executed in a loop.
After the debug mode is enabled, too much data is inserted into the rule_node_debug_event table, which causes the queue to be full. As a result, data cannot be inserted into other tables and telemetry data cannot be uploaded to the cloud.
The logs are as follows：
406 [tb-rule-engine-consumer-56-thread-4 | QK(Main,TB_RULE_ENGINE,system)-7
] INFO  o.t.s.s.q.r.TbRuleEngineQueueConsumerManager - [a77f64c0-abbc-11ef-b9a6-cfcd04431c0a
] Failed to process message: TbMsg(queueName=Main, id=3c241742-70c3-4b10-93b0-ea2ab9a2c012, ts=1734683338242, type=ENTITY_UPDATED, internalType=ENTITY_UPDATED, originator=673ebe50-7370-11ed-ae05-97d2228e9c8a, customerId=null, metaData=TbMsgMetaData(data={ruleNodeId=ad7644d0-b5fc-11ef-aeaf-bfe761b755c3
}), dataType=JSON, data={
    "id": {
        "entityType": "ALARM",
        "id": "4cd8add5-e8ca-4c20-bfe2-9cb450d275ca"
    },
    "createdTime": 1734595926269,
    "tenantId": {
        "entityType": "TENANT",
        "id": "a77f64c0-abbc-11ef-b9a6-cfcd04431c0a"
    },
    "customerId": null,
    "type": "General Alarm",
    "originator": {
        "entityType": "DEVICE",
        "id": "673ebe50-7370-11ed-ae05-97d2228e9c8a"
    },
    "severity": "CRITICAL",
    "acknowledged": false,
    "cleared": false,
    "assigneeId": null,
    "startTs": 1734595926209,
    "endTs": 1734683338217,
    "ackTs": 0,
    "clearTs": 0,
    "assignTs": 0,
    "propagate": false,
    "propagateToOwner": false,
    "propagateToTenant": true,
    "propagateRelationTypes": [],
    "originatorName": "test-001",
    "originatorLabel": "test-001",
    "assignee": null,
    "name": "General Alarm",
    "status": "ACTIVE_UNACK",
    "details": {}
}, ruleChainId=a7675300-b5fb-11ef-aeaf-bfe761b755c3, ruleNodeId=99094c70-bc25-11ef-99ed-d7061ecffb1b, correlationId=null, partition=null, ctx=org.tk.server.common.msg.TbMsgProcessingCtx@cdccf6c, callback=org.tk.server.common.msg.queue.TbMsgCallback$1@29bab440), Last Rule Node: [RuleChain: 测试|RuleNode: ces(99094c70-bc25-11ef-99ed-d7061ecffb1b)
]
2024-12-20 16: 28: 58,
409 [rule-dispatcher-0-7
] INFO  o.t.s.a.r.RuleNodeActorMessageProcessor - onRuleChainToRuleNodeMsgRuleChainToRuleNodeMsg(fromRelationType=),msgTbMsg(queueName=Main, id=53619172-6644-46a3-b06c-a4f89bb45b5e, ts=1734683338321, type=ENTITY_UPDATED, internalType=ENTITY_UPDATED, originator=673ebe50-7370-11ed-ae05-97d2228e9c8a, customerId=null, metaData=TbMsgMetaData(data={ruleNodeId=ad7644d0-b5fc-11ef-aeaf-bfe761b755c3
}), dataType=JSON, data={
    "id": {
        "entityType": "ALARM",
        "id": "4cd8add5-e8ca-4c20-bfe2-9cb450d275ca"
    },
    "createdTime": 1734595926269,
    "tenantId": {
        "entityType": "TENANT",
        "id": "a77f64c0-abbc-11ef-b9a6-cfcd04431c0a"
    },
    "customerId": null,
    "type": "General Alarm",
    "originator": {
        "entityType": "DEVICE",
        "id": "673ebe50-7370-11ed-ae05-97d2228e9c8a"
    },
    "severity": "CRITICAL",
    "acknowledged": false,
    "cleared": false,
    "assigneeId": null,
    "startTs": 1734595926209,
    "endTs": 1734683338313,
    "ackTs": 0,
    "clearTs": 0,
    "assignTs": 0,
    "propagate": false,
    "propagateToOwner": false,
    "propagateToTenant": true,
    "propagateRelationTypes": [],
    "originatorName": "test-001",
    "originatorLabel": "test-001",
    "assignee": null,
    "name": "General Alarm",
    "status": "ACTIVE_UNACK",
    "details": {}
}, ruleChainId=a7675300-b5fb-11ef-aeaf-bfe761b755c3, ruleNodeId=67ab2960-bddc-11ef-813c-17a432ffb01e, correlationId=null, partition=null, ctx=org.tk.server.common.msg.TbMsgProcessingCtx@faa2afe, callback=org.tk.server.service.queue.TbMsgPackCallback@6ff34657),ruleChainId测试
2024-12-20 16: 28: 58,

I wish to end this loop and find out which rule is triggered to create this progress.
Thank you
